# Split Header and Content in curl

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, http-headers

```
curl -L -i google.com
```

I want to split the HEADER and CONTENT from the response in two variables

```
curl -I google.com
curl -L google.com
```

I cant use these two becouse im going to use it with 10000+ links

Both Header and Content can have three or more blank lines, so spliting blank lines wont work everytime

---

I found the answer

```
b=$(curl -LsD h google.com)
h=$(<h)
echo "$h$b"
```

This code works too

```
curl -sLi google.com | 
awk -v bl=1 'bl{bl=0; h=($0 ~ /HTTP\/1/)} /^\r?$/{bl=1} {print $0>(h?"header":"body")}'

header=$(<header)
body=$(<body)
```

Comment: Isn't it illegal for the header to contain blank lines?

Comment: Sometimes with 302 error it shows two headers, so theres a blank line between then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this script:

```
curl -sLi google.com | 
   awk -v bl=1 'bl{bl=0; h=($0 ~ /HTTP\/1/)} /^\r?$/{bl=1} {print $0>(h?"header":"body")}'

header=$(<header)
body=$(<body)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without generating a header and body file?

Comment: OP mentioned a `-D` option for the same